# SBCL Compiler Diagnostic Messages (missing with a "when" with no body)

Tags: common-lisp, compiler-warnings, sbcl

By accident, I recently came across a latent coding error in one of my functions, dealing with a `when` statement. A reduced paraphrase might look like:

```
(defparameter a 0)

(when (or (= a 0)
          (= a 1)
  (* a a)))
```

The problem is a misplaced parenthesis, so it actually is

```
(when (or (= a 0)
          (= a 1)
          (* a a)))
```

In a situation like this, wouldn't it be useful for the compiler to generate either a style warning or note? It seems to me that the meaning of a `when` statement normally implies a condition and a body, even though the body is strictly optional. Of course, a print pretty would have caught this in the editor, but I had copied it from elsewhere. Is there a reason that SBCL does not check for these kinds of mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a print pretty would have caught this in the editor

To discuss the options, I know about:

- [trivial-formatter](https://github.com/hyotang666/trivial-formatter) will format the source code.

  (trivial-formatter:fmt :your-system :supersede)
- [cl-indentify](https://github.com/yitzchak/cl-indentify/) indents the source code. Has a command line utility. I tried it once and it was not bad, but different than Emacs' indentation, thus annoying for me.

  $ cl-indentify bar.lisp

It links to [lispindent](https://github.com/ds26gte/scmindent) but I was less happy with its result.

However, the best would be to not only format the code and re-read it ourselves, but to

#### run checks against a set of rules to warn against code smells

This is what proposes the [lisp-critic](https://github.com/g000001/lisp-critic/). It can critique a function or a file. However:

- (edit) it doesn't really have a Slime integration, we have to either critique a function or a whole file.

  - if you feel adventurous, see an utility of mine [here](https://ciel-lang.github.io/CIEL/#/repl?id=friendly-lisp-critic). It could be an easier way to test snippets that you enter at the REPL.
- it hasn't the rule about `when` without a body (we can easily add it)

And it would be best that the run failed with an error status code if it found a code smell. Again, a little project of mine in beta tries to do that, see [here](https://github.com/vindarel/colisper). It doesn't have much rules now, but I just pushed a check for this. You can call the script:

```
$colisper.sh tests/playground.lisp
```

it shows an error (but doesn't write it in-place by default):

```
 |;; when with no body
 |(when (or (= a 0)
 |          (= a 1)
!|     (* a a))
!|  (error "colisper found a 'when' with a missing body. (we should error the script without this rewrite!)"))
```

and returns with an exit code, so we can use it has a git hook or on a CI pipeline.

Comment: I like the idea of lisp-critic. And the function for critiquing a whole file seems to work fine. Can you suggest the easiest way to remove rules I don’t care about, and add new ones I do care about, if I want to do (ql:quickload :lisp-critic) first? Happy holidays!

Comment: I think you have to clone lisp-critic and edit the rules file, or contribute this feature. (good point there's a critique-whole-file function)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if a *human* writes `(when x)` (or whatever that expands into, perhaps `(if x (progn) nil)`) this is probably a mistake, but when a *program* writes it it may well not be: it may be just some edge case that the program hasn't been smart enough to optimize completely away.  And a huge amount of code that the compiler processes is written by programs, not humans.